# Tracks stops working when volume is specified

Tags: linux, permissions, docker

I am trying to get the [Tracks Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/staannoe/tracks/) to work.

When I run the given command `docker run -d --name=tracks -p 80:80 staannoe/tracks`, everything goes fine. However, if I add a volume with `docker run -d --volume /srv/tracks:/var/www --name=tracks -p 80:80 staannoe/tracks` then suddenly it breaks: After doing the `docker run`, when I point my browser to the Tracks URL, all I get is a 404 error.

I noticed that `/srv/tracks` is always empty as well, unlike `/var/www` in the volume-less case. Notably, `docker logs` reveals that when I specify the volume, I get:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/tracks/public] does not exist
```

I also get this error even if I manually create `/srv/tracks/public`. What is the problem?

***EDIT:*** I am no longer sure if permissions are the problem. I did `sudo chmod 777 /srv/tracks` and I still get the same error. I also tried to `sudo chgrp 33 /srv/tracks` (`33` is apparently `www-data`; by default the directory is owned by `root:root`) and this still didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/var/www` seems to contain data that is needed by your app. When you mount `/srv/tracks` as a volume to `/var/www`, its contents get **hidden** by the contents ov `/srv/tracks`.

According to your warning message:

> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/tracks/public] does not exist

Probably you want to do something like this instead and place the `tracks` folder as a subfolder blow `www` instead of overwriting the whole `www` folder:

```
docker run ... -v /srv/tracks:/var/www/tracks ...
```

Otherwise: if you need to keep the `/srv/www` files but use an other folder to replace `www` you could place the `tracks` files into a different folder like `/bootstrap` during the `Dockerfile` build. And during container startup you simply copy the `/bootstrap` files to the `/srv/www` by providing your own little startup script.

**EDIT**: Make sure you do not mount an empty `tracks` folder into `/var/www/tracks`. In that folder there are some files expected. When they are not found you get an `HTTP 404`. Those folders are required on top level:

```
$ docker exec -it tracks ls /var/www/tracks
COPYING       README.md  bin        db        lib     public  vendor
Gemfile       Rakefile   config     doc       log     test
Gemfile.lock  app    config.ru  features  mkdocs.yml  tmp
```

Make sure that your custom `tasks` folder that you use as a volume is based on the original images contents.

Comment: I still get the same error with `-v /srv/tracks:/var/www/tracks`. Furthermore, in the dockerfile, there is already the command `VOLUME ["/var/www"]`. I thought this was supposed to resolve the hiding issue?

Comment: So I've tried commenting out [that line](https://github.com/staannoe/tracks/blob/master/Dockerfile#L50) in the dockerfile, then building and running that. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Could you provide us the contents of your `/srv/tracks` folder which you try to mount? I assume it is a super-set of the `tracks` folder included in the original image (otherwise when files were missing there the error would be obvious).

Comment: I updated my answer providing some more information about the `tracks` volume.